# Square-free sieve over number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I am trying to work on extending various methods to study square-free values of polynomials (or more generally, $k$-free values) over general rings of integers, and a literature review has yielded only two articles that seems to address this problem: a 1993 Journal of Number Theory paper by Gouvea, linked here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X83710127#
and a 1989 article in the same journal, by Hinz:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X89900875

Are there any other papers or results in the 22 years since that studies this problem?